# How to decide the wing span?

Tags: aircraft-design, glider

How would you decide the wing span for a delta wing glider? 
Also how would it relate to the main chord length?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. This question is very likely to be closed as too broad, because it is a topic that entire books could be written about without arriving at a single solution. If you could elaborate on the requirements this wing would have to meet, it could become answerable. Also, just to be sure, are you familiar with the concept of wing aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a delta wing for a glider would not be ideal because delta wings have a lower Coefficient of lift as well as a lower aspect ratio. However you can find wing span by using the formula in the link attached: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/geom.html **AR=s^2/A**
when you use this formula you can get a idea on how well it would glide. For example the B-52 has a span of 185' and area of 4000 sq.ft., this gave a AR # of 8.56. The Concorde (Delta Wing) has a AR of 1.83 with a span of 85' and area of 3856 sq.ft. Using this formula you can determine a good AR, once you have done that you can use your numbers you have found to find the chord length by A/s=c. That should give you the chord length of your aircraft.